# Jquery Timer with delay input as an Array

Tags: jquery, timer

```
var delay=[1000,5000,2000,1000,1500] // (in milliseconds)
window.ChatTimer = $.timer(updateTimer, delay, true).once();
function updateTimer() {
// Do something
}
```

I want this jQuery timer to take the different delay every time, however it is taking the same delay each time it executes..... 
I am using jQuery Script file. U can find it below
https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer/blob/master/jquery.timer.js

Comment: typing error... Consider it same

Comment: which all plugins you are using. Could you please update your question and put the links to those plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var delays=[1000,5000,2000,1000,1500] // (in milliseconds)
var delay = delays[Math.floor(Math.random() * delays.length)];

window.ChatTimer = $.timer(updateTimer, delay, true).once();
function updateTimer() {
  // Do something
}
```

Im not sure what exactly do you want to achieve - it will pick RANDOM delay each time, if you need it somehow ordered, code would be different, but you didn't provided enough info.

[EDIT]
If i understand correctly this is what you want: after each tick of the timer, you want next tick to be executed after time next value from delays array:

```
var delays=[1000,5000,2000,1000,1500]; // (in milliseconds)
var i=0;

window.ChatTimer = $.timer(updateTimer, delays[i++], true);
function updateTimer() {
  // Do something
  if (i >= delays.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  window.ChatTimer.set({time: delays[i++]});
}
```

Comment: I wnt this function to pick delay as given in the array sequentially

Comment: update timer function should be called after 1000, 5000,2000 ms respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.floor() and Math.random() function to decide subscript for particular array.And after generate subscript you can get value that associated to particular subscript in array.

```
Suppose you want to return a random number between 1 and 10:
index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
```

If your array having 10 element then you can use return value of above function as a index to get element from array.
example - arr_name[index]

So you see following example

```
var delays=[1000,5000,2000,1000,1500] // (in milliseconds)
//get random index for delays array and after that get element that associated to that index.
index = delays[Math.floor(Math.random() * delays.length)];
window.ChatTimer = $.timer(updateTimer, index, true).once();
function updateTimer() {
// Do something
}
```

here delays.length - indicate number of element exist in delays array.